How to make responsive percentage div with fluid-tailwind
I use tailwind css and fluid-tailwind plugin.
but I'm new to this plugin. I'm facing situation to make div responsive.
here is my code:
<div class="flex">
  <div class="w-1/2">A</div>
  <div class="w-1/2">B</div>
</div>

and my question is. how to make it responsive in small screen using fluid-tailwind instead of manually using tailwind class?
I want it displayed as w-2/2 in small screen
I already use this following css class selector, but not work
~w-2/2/1/2

~w-[2/2]/[1/2]

~sm/md:~w-2/2/1/2

Anyone experienced using fluid-tailwind, could you please help me. Thanks in advance
